# HttpClient shared instance with different sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, concurrency, httpclient

#### Context

The recommended way to use `HttpClient` is to create one instance and share it (according to the Microsoft documentation). There are many examples out there where using an `HttpClient` per request (on a server) yielded issues.

#### Problem

In my situation I have to run up to 20 simultaneous "sessions" which cannot interfere with one another. By "session" I mean isolated set of operations on a service or multiple services. No data should be shared between these sessions and specifically cookies.

These sessions are long lasting sessions (can last for days). But there may be only a maximum of 20 concurrent sessions at the same time. A slow start while instantiating these sessions is acceptable (up to 5 seconds).

#### Question

Should I use a pool? Should I reuse the same `HttpClient` instance? Should I spawn up to 20 `HttpClient`s? Moreover, considering that they run concurrently, is it correct to assume that concurrent calls to a single `HttpClient` will be blocking?

Comment: It depends on what else your server is doing. If it is not using a large number of TCP connections for other applications then 20 instances of HttpClient, each with one session is nothing.

Comment: @Crowcoder It's a GraphQL API server so it will receive a decent amount of HTTP POST requests which are handled via ASP.NET Core 2.

Comment: Then I would try to use a single client but vary requests by `HttpRequestMessage` instead of setting any properties on the client itself. [See my blog](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/07/01/using-httpclient-as-it-was-intended-because-youre-not/) for recipies.

Comment: @Crowcoder By using a single instance will I actually be able to use the client in parallel or will it just block until another session completed the previous request?

Comment: It won't block, it is designed to be accessed by multiple threads. Just don't do any blocking yourself by adding `.Result` or `.Wait()` on any calls, everything should be fully async.

Comment: @Crowcoder Perfect, if you add that as an answer I'll accept it as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at HttpClientFactory? https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore

Comment: It is continuously amazing to me how things that were easy with HttpWebRequest are now hard with HttpClient. Messed up API design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendation for creating only a single instance of `HttpClient` is because it creates a TCP connection that persists for a period of time. Eventually, it will get garbarge collected or closed naturally, but in the meantime, you could potentially exhaust the maximum amount of open connections on the server. There's also a bit of resource utilization from each connection that could prove problematic when stacked.

However, this is one of those things where there's no hard and fast rule. Certain things, like creating a new `HttpClient` per operation, are obviously problematic, but generally one instance per request to your server (not per request sent through `HttpClient`) shouldn't be problematic unless you're servicing a high number of concurrent requests.

You can also just make it a singleton across your application. `HttpClient` is not technically a user or session-specific thing. It would only be problematic if your changing default headers that should not be leaked across sessions. For example, you'd want to attach something like an `Authorization` header as part of creating a request, not as a default header when setting up the client. As long as you're smart about how you use it, there's no problem having it shared. That being "smart about how you use it" thing can sometimes be a point of failure, though. Even if you are, will the next developer be. More to the point, will they even know they *should* be? You might even forget, yourself.

Personally, I'd start making it request-scoped, where each request to your web application gets a separate instance, but that same instance will be used for all operations with `HttpClient` during that request. You can then do some profiling to see how the server is handling this, and if it does become a problem, then you can look for alternative solutions.

Comment: It wouldn't even be a single instance per request. It would be a single instance per job. My api allows the user to specify jobs that can be run for days. The start and stop of a job is something that happens very rarely and has a cap of 20 maximum concurrent jobs at any given time. So the `HttpClient` would be instanciated once and used many times for many hours until it either finishes the job or the user stops it.

Comment: So usage wise would be a lot less.